# js-cookie with sameSite None & secure

Tags: javascript, cookies, chromium, samesite, js-cookie

how do i use js-cookie with sameSite set to none & secure? is this something like this?

`Cookies.set("name", "value", {SameSite : "None; secure" });`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do the following:

```
  Cookies.set('name', 'value', {
    sameSite: 'none',
    secure: true
  })
```

Comment: Thank you but this code still can not work in an iframe. Can you check please?

Answer (score 5):

You can try simply with:

```
document.cookie = "witcher=Geralt; SameSite=None; Secure"
```

Cookie is set with above attributes:
[image: cookie]